# How do i get the next value and previous in a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose i have an `ID` column that has the values 1 , 5 , 7 .What SQL statement can i use to get the next value of in the column based on another.

Example : The next value after 1 is  5.

Example 2 : the  value before 7 is 5

Comment: What will happen in case of first and last value of table

Comment: If you are looking for a static result (ie, the answer for a single, already known ID), it's as simple as `SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID > 1 ORDER BY ID`. If not, you should edit your question to further clarify the type of query you want to perform.

Comment: @PareshJ i am expecting some error in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any window functions or CTEs:

```
select
    t.id,
    (select max(t1.id) from tbl t1 where t1.id < t.id) as previd,
    (select min(t2.id) from tbl t2 where t2.id > t.id) as nextid
from tbl t
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some great Windowed functions for working across records in later versions of SQL Server (2012+).  But in 2008 these aren't available.  Instead you could use an OUTER APPLY.  This will allow you to filter a sub query using values from your main query.

[Outer Apply Query Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/401575/outer-apply-example)

```
WITH SampleValues AS
    (
        /* This CTE creates some sample values.
         */
        SELECT
            r.n
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    (1),
                    (5),
                    (7)
            ) AS r(n)
    )
SELECT
    o.n,
    prev.Previous_n,
    [next].Next_n
FROM
    SampleValues AS o
        OUTER APPLY
            (
                -- Find the previou value by looking for the TOP 1 before the current.
                SELECT TOP 1 
                    o.n     AS Original_n,
                    p.n     AS Previous_n
                FROM
                    SampleValues AS p
                WHERE
                    p.n < o.n
                ORDER BY
                    p.n DESC
            ) AS prev 
        OUTER APPLY
            (   
                -- Find the next value by looking for the TOP 1 after the current.
                SELECT TOP 1 
                    n.n     AS Original_n,
                    n.n     AS Next_n
                FROM
                    SampleValues AS n
                WHERE
                    n.n > o.n
                ORDER BY
                    n.n ASC
            )AS [next]      
;
```